# Prove that for any real numbers $x_1,\cdots, x_n, \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} x_i x_j\ge 0$

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality, summation, contest-math

> Let $D_1,\cdots, D_n$ be n disks in $\mathbb{R}^2$. For any $i,j,$ let $a_{ij}$ denote the area of $D_i\cap D_j.$ Prove that for any real numbers $x_1,\cdots, x_n, \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} x_i x_j\ge 0$

Note that if $\chi_{D_i}((x,y))$ denotes the characteristic function equal to 1 if $(x,y)\in D_i$ and 0 otherwise, then $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} x_i x_j = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \int_{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2} \chi_{D_i} ((x,y)) \chi_{D_j} ((x,y)) x_i x_j = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \int_{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2} \chi_{D_i} x_i \cdot \chi_{D_j} x_j.$ I wish I could just say that this last value equals $(\sum_{i=1}^n \int_{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2} \chi_{D_i}((x,y)) x_i)^2$, but that assumes that $\int_{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2} \chi_{D_i} x_i \cdot \chi_{D_j} x_j = (\int \chi_{D_i} \cdot \int \chi_{D_j}) x_i x_j$.

Comment: Try taking the integral outside both sums. You get $\int_{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^n} \big(\sum_{i=1}^n \chi_{D_i}(x,y) x_i\big)^2 \, dx \, dy$.

Comment: Note also that this works for arbitrary (measurable) regions, not just disks.

Comment: This doesn't really help, but it's interesting to note that you're basically being asked to prove that a matrix $(a_{ij})$ defined as in your problem is positive semi-definite. Phrased that way, it feels like this is probably a standard result.

Comment: Actually, this formulation almost immediately leads to an answer when you realize that $(a_{ij})$ is the matrix of inner products of characteristic functions. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1633517/is-the-matrix-filled-with-the-areas-of-pairwise-intersections-of-disks-in-a-plan) post for an answer to your question.