# Minkowski sum of two Objects

Tags: summation

I'm trying to implement the [ClearPath pathfinding algorithm](http://gamma.cs.unc.edu/CA/ClearPath.pdf), that relys on velocity obstacles.
It is assumed, that both objects have a circular hull.
However, I do not understand how to calculate the minkowski sum of two objects.
[Here's an excerpt from the paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gNjI.png)

Apparently, the minkowski sum is simply the sum of two sets (here all possible velocities that yield a collision), but it is not explained how to calculate the set of those velocity vectors. It is only explained how to calculate a single velocity vector ( λ(p,v) ). Am I missing something ?

Also, what does this mean ?

> let -A denote the object A reflected in its reference point

What is an objects reference point, and what does it mean to reflect said point ?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition for information about Minkowski sum. The Minkowski sum of two circular discs is another circular disc (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/444845/minkowski-sum-of-two-disks). If $-A$ means $A$ reflected in its reference point, then I think "reference point" just means the origin of the coordinate system you are using to represent $A$.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply.
But **how** does one compute the minkowski sum of 2 disks ? 2 convex polygons is easy, all you have to do, is to add up the vertices of both polygons.
But how does that work with 2 disks ? I don't have vertices, all I have is the centrum as well as the radius.

Comment: See the MSE link in my comment.

Comment: I have. If I understand it correctly, this is basically the set of a disk
D(p,r)={p+u∣u∈D(0,r)}
But how do I work with that set ? A polygon has a fixed amount of vertices, a disk, however, consists of an infinite amount of points.
So, what do I actually add up when taking the minkowski sum of 2 disks ?

Comment: You can represent the disc by the coordinates of the centre point $\mathbf{p}$  and the radius $r$. The formula in the MSE link shows you how you to combine two such representations to get the representation of the Minkowski sum.